# C++: most efficient algorithm to find all consecutive subsequences of given length in a sequence

Tags: c++, performance

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to **extract all subsequences** of a given length from a given sequence over a fixed alphabet (lets say its 0,1,2,3) and **also which sub sequences were read** and which not.

So for a sequence

```
[0,1,3,2,4,3,1]
```

and subsequence length 2 I want to get

```
[[0,1],[1,3],[3,2],[2,4],[4,3],[3,1],
```

and the boolean array

```
 00 01 02 03 10 11 12 13 20 21 22 23 30 31 32 33
[ 0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0].
```

My **current approach** is something like this:

```
size_t              alphSize     = 4;
size_t              subSeqLength = 2;
std::deque<size_t>  currSub;
std::vector<bool>   subSeqRead ( pow( alphSize , subSeqLength ) );

for (size_t i = 0; i < seqLength - subSeqLength + 1; ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < subSeqLength; ++j)
    {
        currSub.pop_front();
        currSub.push_back(sequence[i+j]);
    }
    if (currSub.size() == subSeqLength)
    {
        subSeqRead[ arrayPos(currSub) ] = true;
    }
}
```

where

```
arrayPos(currSub)
```

works on a Heap tree structure to calculate the position of a subsequence in the boolean array without multiplications.

However, this is somewhere close to

```
O( seqLength * subSeqLength )
```

**Does anybody know something faster?**

In my scenario the alphabet size indeed is 4, the subsequence length will be something >=6 and sequence length anything from 10^4 to 10^6. And I need to process a lot of those sequences.

Going from there my input sequence might have some wild card digits (let's say its "w"), in which case for

```
[1,w,2]
```

I will have to treat this as if I read

```
[[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]].
```

Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure this is the bottleneck of your program? Or are you just theoretically interested?

Comment: Does your current code even work? What is `back` in your inner loop and why do you repeat that so often?

Comment: It seems like you should only need one for loop for this one. What does your inner for loop do? Why do you need to pop and push more than once?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Let X hold the value that represents the subsequence (its index in the boolean vector) that ends at the current position.

Let Y hold the value alphabet size ^ subsequence length (the size of the boolean vector or `pow( alphSize , subSeqLength )`).

1. Set X to 0
2. Iterate through the sequence and for each step:

   1. Multiply X by the alphabet size.
   2. Add the current value of the sequence to X
   3. Set X to X % Y

   This should be equivalent to adding a digit in the base of the alphabet size and truncating the first one to make it only as long as the subsequence.

   Now, if we are at least at the position equivalent to the subsequence length, we can set the value in the boolean vector at X to true.

This doesn't generate the subsequences as vectors though, so you'd have to build them from the resulting boolean vector, which would be slightly faster, since there can't be any duplicities.

Answer (score 0):

With your concrete numbers you can represent each element with two bits. 
Since you want to represent the final array, I assume subsequences cannot get too long and hence the array fits in memory.

just use the value of the subsequence (map each char of the alphabet to 0, 1, 2 , 3 (00 01 10 11 resp.)  as index in a `vector<bool>` (simple bitmap) of size alphSize ^ SubSeqLength.
Note that this also works with larger alphbets but sequences will take more space.
The index in that array / bitvector corresponds to a subsequence.

For example the subsequence 1030 is 01001100 and hence index 76.

Go through the sequence and take each (seqLength - subSeqLength + 1) as it's uint value and set the corresponding element to true.

gives you

```
O(seqLength - subSeqLength + 1) = O(seqLength).
```

If your input has a whole byte for each element (like ascii strings), you can still shift and mask to create the compact representation of the subsequence before you set the result array. This should also work for alphabets with size greater than 4. Note that alphabet Size and subsequence Length are the limitting factor. But since you want to produce the full output array anyways, I assume it'll fit in memory.

basically this is the same as your suggestions but "arrayPos" is (almost) free